# Magento 2 , How to get customer public ip address and send that public address with order inforamtion

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods, ip-address

I am integration `PayFort Payment` method with my `Magento 2` store and `PayFort` team review my store and comments from pay fort team was.
Please make sure to detect the customer browsing `IP` address which is a public `IP` address and pass it to customer IP parameter currently you are passing the following value in customer _ip parameter and this is not my public IP address ( 52.94.36.25)
Now how I can get customer public IP and send that order information.

Comment: from this code to you will find public ip <?php
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
echo $externalIp = $m[1];
?>

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya in which file ?

Comment: where your customer _ip parameter is define you need to assign public ip and it will found in your app/code/ your PayFort module.

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya getting this file_get_contents(checkip.dyndns.com/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp64\www\public_ip\index.php on line 2

Comment: use http before url. http://checkip.dyndns.com

Comment: is it work for you..?

Comment: No , its not : preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset